# Hide/Show Div after form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I'm having some trouble getting this to work, pretty simple all I am wanting to do is show a div once my html form is submitted.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showHide() {
   var div = document.getElementById(hidden_div);
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
     div.style.display = '';
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
</script>

</head>


<body>

<form method="post" name="installer">

<label>Home Keyword</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="hello" value="">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" onsubmit="showHide()">

</form>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
<p>Show me when form is submitted :) </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Move the onsubmit attribute to the form. Also, don't use "submit" as a form control name as it shaddows the form's submit method. In the above, *form.submit* will reference the control, not the method, so calling it will throw an error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're just missing quotes around "hidden_div" in your `document.getElementById("hidden_div")` call!

But actually, your page is probably posting back, resetting the state of the page and thus leaving hidden_div seemingly always in a hidden state -- are you intending on handling the form submission via AJAX?

If you want to see the intended behavior, you should move the `showHide()` call to the `<form>` element, and return false after it:

```
<form method="post" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">
```

and leave the submit button as:

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
```

Also note that you haven't self-closed the `<input />` button tag, or given any text to show inside it.

Comment: Thank you Cory yes that does seem to do the trick and haha yes I have the quotes within my original code but they got lost in translation, I think my coffee needs topping up :P

Comment: There is no need to "close" the input tag, the OP has not indicated that XHTML is being used and it is extremely rare to use it on the web.

Comment: @RobG: I only inferred it from the fact that she was doing so with the `<br />` tags, but you could be right.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put `showhide` function on form `onsubmit` instead of `input`

```
<form method="post" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide()">
```

you are also missing quotes as @Cory mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this example works for you , I have used two different ways
first One for Hiding Form and second One for Showing DIV

```js
  document.forms['myFirstForm'].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    // Do something with the form's data here
    this.style['display'] = 'none';
    event.preventDefault();
  }); 
   function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="" class="m-md-5 px-md-5" method="post" name="myFirstForm">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-5" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="myDIV" class="2" style="display:none">
  <h1>ThankYou</h1>
  <h6>We will get back to you shortly on the same.</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is many years old, so it's probably not that useful to submit an answer at this late date!