# How To Hide A Div Element After Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

going to make this quick. I am working on a site that takes an id number, queries a database, and then returns the data in on the same page in a nice table. I am having a strange problem where the `input` box (part of a form) will not disappear. Here is the code relevant to this:

Form:

```
<div class="search_box">    
<form method="POST" id="search_form">
        <input type="text" name="person_id" class="submission-boxes" placeholder="Person ID" required><br>
        <input type="submit" name="newperson" class="submission-btn" value="+ Add Person" id="find_em" onclick="SwapDivsWithClick()">
    </form>
</div>
```

The `.css` relevant to the form:

```
 form{
width: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
input{
width: 50%;
padding: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;

}
```

The function that is `echo`'d within the `php` script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                        function SwapDivsWithClick()
                            {
                             $( 'div' ).remove( '.search_box' );        
                            }
                </script>"
```

This is what I am currently trying at the moment after a long string of trial and error. I think the problem is when the user submits the form the php script executes faster than the page can reload, so when it does reload it inherits the style from the attached `.css` stylesheet. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

**NOTE:** I've already tried replacing the `search_box` class with the necessary information. The same sort of thing was happening.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: May be you will find your solution please try this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156157/hide-show-div-after-form-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use JavaScript here. Simply check whether the form has been submitted or not, and based on that hide the `div` element.

```
<div class="search_box" <?php if(isset($_POST['newperson'])){ echo "style='display:none'"; } ?>>    
    <form method="POST" id="search_form">
        <input type="text" name="person_id" class="submission-boxes" placeholder="Person ID" required><br>
        <input type="submit" name="newperson" class="submission-btn" value="+ Add Person" id="find_em">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost works. The issue is that it needs to hide the box after the database has been queried and returns the result of them either existing (thus deleting the box) or not (thus keeping the box to search again)

Comment: @Ethan So if the user already exists, it should not hide the search box, right?

Comment: No, what happens is the user puts in an id number into the search box (form). When they press submit it queries the database to see if a) anyone exists with that id number and then if so b) return all of their data into a results div WHILE simultaneously hiding the original search div.

Comment: @Ethan This is what this code snippet does. When a user hits the submit button, the search box will disappear, while you can display the results in another div. What behavior are you getting from this code snippet?

Comment: Hmmm let me try something, one second.

Comment: @Ethan Or may be you're looking this kind of solution, [http://pastebin.com/YA4dv9Gx](http://pastebin.com/YA4dv9Gx)

Comment: What happens is that the search box hides regardless of whether or not a person with the specified id is found. So right now I am trying redisplay the search box if the query returns false. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: @Ethan Edit your question and share your PHP code as well.

Comment: I figured it out. If my query returned false I just ran this script here: `<script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('search_box').style.display= 'block' 
        </script>` It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Ethan Glad I could help, *somewhat*.;-) You can also accomplish the same thing using only PHP, give it a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an onsubmit function that will fire when the form is submitted.

```
<form method="POST" id="search_form" onsubmit="SwapDivsWithClick()">
```

```js
 function SwapDivsWithClick() {
  $('div').remove('.search_box');        
}
```

```css
form {
     width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_box">    
<form method="POST" id="search_form" onsubmit="SwapDivsWithClick()">
        <input type="text" name="person_id" class="submission-boxes" placeholder="Person ID" required><br>
        <input type="submit" name="newperson" class="submission-btn" value="+ Add Person" id="find_em" onclick="SwapDivsWithClick()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is is issue I am talking about. When I try this the search box deletes for a split second and the results appear at the top where they should, then the search box reappears and pushes the results down.

Comment: That isn't happening in this code. Is your script reloading the page after submit? If you're reloading the page, any DOM manipulation will be moot.

Comment: No, it just fetches the results then tries to `echo` them into the page. No reloading at all.

Comment: What does the response code look like? Does it contain the form?

Comment: Yes, and the form is displayed on the page itself'

Comment: Well that's why it's reappearing. The hide from the onsubmit will only hide the elements present when fired. You'll have to include additional logic to show the response form or not. Hard to say exactly without seeing it and knowing the different logical paths.