# Show a div after the form is submitted (or after pressing the "Send" button)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

My task is to make a div visible after submitting a form. The problem is: after submitting the form, the div appears for 0.5 sec, then it disappears again.

This is the relevant code part. I want to show the div with id="data".

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="show_div()">
  <div class="request">
    <center>
      <img id="logo" src="/img/n1_red.png" alt="">
      <h1 id="t_request" class="item">Account Name</h1>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="request" name="Request" value="<?php echo $cloud; ?>" class="item"><br/>
      <input type="submit" class="bttn" class="item" onclick="show_div()" value="Send" /><br/>
    </center>
  </div>
  
  <div id="data" style="display:none">
    <h2 id="t_mail">Mail</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $Email; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_password">Password</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" id="pass_visibility" onclick="unhide_password()" value="Unhide pass"/>
    <label for="pass_visibility" id="pass_visibility_label">(Unhide pass)</label>
    <p class="pass_result" id="text_hidden_pass">Password is hidden.</p>
    <p class="result" id="text_pass" style="display:none"><?php echo $Password; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_total_gb">Total GB</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $Total_GB; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_gb_used">Used GB</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $GB_Used; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_about">About</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $About; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_key">KEY</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $Decryption; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_authy">Authy</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $Authy; ?></p>
    
    <h2 id="t_nr_acc">Acc name</h2>
    <p class="result"><?php echo $Name; ?></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is the JavaScript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById("data");

function show_div() {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
```

I tried to do this in 2 different methods:

First one was to add *onclick="show_div()* to the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" class="bttn" class="item" onclick="show_div()" value="Send" /><br/>
```

Then I added *onsubmit="show_div()"* to the submit form.

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="show_div()">
```

As I said, with this method (after submitting the form/clicking the button) the result is not as expected. The div appears for 0.5 sec, then it disappears again.

Not sure if you need, but here is the CSS for id="data":

```
#data {
    border-top: dashed 3px rebeccapurple;
    border-left: dashed 3px rebeccapurple;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

And here the PHP code:

```
$cloud = "";
$Email = "";
$Password = "";
$Name = "";
$Total_GB = "";
$GB_Used = "";
$About = "";
$Decryption = "";
$Authy = "";



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 



    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "xxx";


    $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);

    if (!$con) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    mysql_select_db("xxx", $con); 


    $cloud = $_POST["Request"];

    // Query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Clouds WHERE Name = '$cloud' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result >= 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $Email = $row['Email'];
            $Password = $row['Password'];
            $Name = $row['Name'];
            $Total_GB = $row['Total_GB'];
            $GB_Used = $row['GB_Used'];
            $About = $row['About'];
            $Decryption = $row['Decryption'];
            $Authy = $row['Authy'];
            
            }
    } else {
        //$error_not_found = "Account not found!";
    }
}
```

I am missing something? Any advice for me? Thanks

[Another Stack Overflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156157/hide-show-div-after-form-submit)
I checked everything. I followed her tips too. No result. Well... The same result

Comment: The form will submit to the page defined in `action`, moving the user’s browser to that page (thus only showing the div until the browser paints the next page). If you want to submit data without this default behavior, submit the data using AJAX.

Comment: Then what about showing the div after pressing the submit button, after the form is submitted? I'm new to HTML and I don't really know what is/how should I work with AJAX. Sorry.

Comment: When you are submitting the form, does the page reloads ?

Comment: I don't think so. I'll post the PHP code too

Comment: The page will reload when you submit the form. You can cancel the form submission event, for example: https://jsbin.com/rehipoboku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: OK. I found the solution. At the end of the script I have to write: "return false;" and then to add " onsubmit="return show_div()" ". Thanks for the help guys :D

Comment: A little question guys... I don't know if I should create a new question for this.. So I followed @badsyntax and I found a way to display my div. but I can't resubmit the form again :/. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This is a snippet you may use. It is not possible to show a div and send the form together, see the comment of esque above.

```
<form id="form1" action="..." method="post">
  <!-- here your form fileds -->
</form>

// true = show div --- false = send form
var showDiv = true;

// form id selector
var myForm = document.querySelector("#form1");

// bind submit event to form
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  if (showDiv == false) {
    console.log('send form');
    return;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Show div, form not send');
  var div = document.getElementById("data");
  div.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: it is possible, by adding the "return false;" after showing the div (in js). Credits @badsyntax

Comment: This is a basic event handler for the "submit" event. You can use it for an AJAX response from the server, or you can use it for a popup div. If you want to send the form from the popup div then put an OK button on the div that will submit the form when clicking on this button.